# unknown module in my server to get PHP errors in HTML tables

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Sorry to ask this... I manage Apache and PHP in my computer.
But having installed a lot of things, I've lost track of some of them. (Things I find really useful to have at my job, or to restore in case of emergency).

The problem is that I have installed this thing which displays PHP errors in a nice and colored html table, but can't remember what I have installed or configured to get it work like it.

Can you give me a hint about it?

I'm using Debian Lenny, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2

Here's a screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/attachment.php?attachmentid=3796&d=1276031845))</sub>

Thank you very much for reading.
Javier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't see your screenshot, but it could be Xdebug. http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace